# Chrome Developer Tool not highlighting xhr request when clicking link in console

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

It is somehow annoying to filter requests in the Network tab just to check the headers, response, etc. of a request.

Previously, checking the headers of a request is so easy. Just click the url in the console and the request name will be highlighted in the network tab.

[image: chrome dev tool]

I have already tried clearing cache/history/cookies, restarting chrome, and even reinstalled a new one. However, the problem's still there.

Is this a bug? Has anyone experience something like this? How do you fix this?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just updated Chrome to v 62.0.3202 and it seems to be working again...I think the old behavior was to leave the XHR highlighted until it was clicked again, now it's just a yellow pulse to quickly highlight the record. Anyway, better than nothing...

Comment: only problem is it doesn't focus on the request. you need to manually scroll the request grid then click the xhr in console. well, as you said, better than nothing.

Comment: I t has not worked for me for over a year. Am i missing something.. it is really getting annoying now on big pages cause I cannot see where the stupid request is.. i just need to inspect the payload but I spend minutes searching for the actual request, after clicking on it.

Comment: I just looked closer and there is a preset filter on the top. Set to XHR and all the other guff is filtered out.. Much easier to find the requests now

Answer (score 0):

It's doesn't work after chrome 61.0.3163 update. Seems bug